# how to stop videoview if we change fragment one to others?

Tags: android

I have two fragments on a single fragments.
first fragment is for normal video and second fragment is for trending video.
when I move from first fragment to second fragment first fragment's video is still playing in background.
I found on pause or on start methods to solve problem but my fragments is in viewPager so it didn't work.
I found also another way setuservisiblehint but problem is that my videoview is in adapter ,
so how can i play or pause video in fragment using setuservisible methods.
if anyone can help me then plese do.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

stop your video view when your fragment method call onDetach(). like this:

```
override fun onDetach() {
    super.onDetach()
    videoView.stop()
}
```

Comment: actually my videoview is in adapter how to get videoview in my fragment to work on it.

Comment: if your video view in recycler view then use this library : https://github.com/Krupen/AutoplayVideos